# Chasing Fish after feeding

Tags: behavior, fish

I have a comet and shubunkin and after I feed them everyday the comet chases the shubunkin. It doesn't look nasty (no biting) and it isn't competition for food because he only does it when it has all gone. He swims into the base of her tail bumping her.

I thought it may be what they do when breeding but they are young fish, is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like classic goldfish mating behaviour. When the male is ready to mate, it will chase / pursue the female and wait for the female to eventually release her eggs. Check if the male has small white spots on their gills. This can be a sign of mating maturity.

In my experience, young fish often perform these same mating behaviours before they are actually able to mate (or before they understand how).

#### Why after feeding?

The fact it happens after feeding could be due to a number of things:

- The feeding brings them into close proximity of each other which triggers the male to begin again.
- The food stimulates the male to begin attempting to mate. Often a change in environment (such as feeding schedule, water change schedule, lighting, PH etc) can trigger fish to begin mating.
- It might just be that you notice it when you're already at the tank feeding them and it does happen at other times.

#### Things to look out for

- Make sure that the male's chasing isn't to the detriment of the female's health. (Sometimes they can get a bit carried away and chase continuously). Providing hiding places can help with this.
- Males can get a bit 'nippy' towards the end of the mating. Watch that the female's fins don't get destroyed by this (unlikely to happen but something to mindful of).
- If they are successful, you'll have more fish! Hurray! But make sure you've got a plan.

#### Additional Reading

Here are some useful articles I found which expand up what I've written here:

- [How do goldfish Mate (thegoldfishtank.com)](http://thegoldfishtank.com/goldfish-care/breeding/how-do-goldfish-mate/)
- [Goldfish Behaviour (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldfish#Behaviour)
- [Video of mating behaviour (Youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAauuOYOhF0)